# Cómo realizar formularios previos al pago en woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress

Quiero desarrollar una web donde al comprar un producto antes de ir al pago etc, quiero que rellenen unos formularios con una documentación. No se si esto se puede desarrollar con woocommerce o se debería de hacer algún tipo de php?

El ejemplo lo he tomado de esta pagina web: http://www.nienumberonline.com/apply-nie/?fid=0&pl=2

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrías incluir el formulario que necesitas dentro de la página del carrito de `woocomerce`. Sus plantillas se encuentran en `woocommerce/templates/cart/`. Aquí se suelen mostrar los productos que has añadido al carrito junto con sus precios, iva y el total del pedido, así como un botón para comenzar el proceso de pedido. Podrías poner el formulario en esta plantilla y que el comportamiento sea algo como que no te deje comenzar el proceso de pedido hasta que rellenes dicho formulario.

Comment: Gracias Hechi, en esa plantilla puedo añadir formularios vía php entiendo, es decir puedo añadir los campos que necesite verdad y luego para procesarlos? o puedo añadir un shortcode de un formulario de contact form? si te fijas en la url que he pasado lo hace distinto, habría alguna manera de realizarlo así?

Comment: @AitorUdabe Los campos que que quieres añadir, ¿son datos de facturación como DNI, teléfono, etc?, Sí es así, woocomerce ya tiene un formulario por defecto para que un usuario introduzca sus datos de facturación antes de llegar a la pasarela de pago, incluso puedes añadir campos nuevos a dicho formulario. De todos modos te recomiendo que hagas una instalación de woocomerce y le eches un vistazo a todas sus funcionalidades primero.

Comment: No debería introducir, nombre completo, pasaporte nombre,numero de pasaporte, ciudadanía,nombre del padre, nombre de la madre, ciudad, cumpleaños, si esta casado o no, otro dato más y algunos más que ahora mismo no me acuerdo

Comment: @AitorUdabe Ya tienes algunas pistas, ahora te recomiendo que intentes hacer algo por tus propios medios y sí no llegas a una solución, te animo a hacer una pregunta más específica con lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Pero en esa plantilla puedo utilizar un formulario php o via un shortcode para que llame a contact form verdad?

Answer (score 0):

Inserta un formulario de Contact Form 7 en un producto de WooCommerce
este plugin

https://www.webempresa.com/blog/inserta-un-formulario-de-contact-form-7-en-un-producto-de-woocommerce.html